# "Circuit rank" but for vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

A graph's circuit rank is the minimum number of edges that have to be removed for the graph to become a tree or forest. Is there a term that represents the minimum number of *vertices* that we must remove to get a tree or forest?

I am working on a project that involves reducing cyclic graphs to trees by removing vertices, but I can't seem to find a term that refers to the quantity above. Vertex connectivity is the closest I've found, but it is still a different concept.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feeding findstat with the first few values yields https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001331, which in particular links to a wikipedia page on the concept.